# Show ID onclick JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi sorry in advance if this has already been asked but I can't find the answer.

I have a set of links that trigger certain ids to show onclick, it works but the one link is suppose to trigger 2 ids to show. My javascript knowledge is not great. Thanks for any help.

Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/louise-fourie/pen/abVdwyZ

```
      
<li>
        <a href="#!"  class="article-btn" onclick="show('el-57d5b6f71db32029');">Fitness & Wellness</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#!"  class="article-btn"  onclick="show('el-57d5b6f71db32029');show('el-e881a23a64890108');">Business</a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#!"  class="article-btn" onclick="show('el-65ebd7b2380005a1');">Arts & Entertainment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

<div class="articles">
  <div id="el-57d5b6f71db32029">fitness</div>
   <div  id="el-e881a23a64890108">business</div>
  <div  id="el-65ebd7b2380005a1">art</div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
var divs = ["el-57d5b6f71db32029", "el-e881a23a64890108", "el-65ebd7b2380005a1"];

        var visibleId = null;
        function show(id) {
           for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          if(visibleId !== id) {
            
            visibleId = id;
          
          }
           }
          hide();
        }
        function hide() {
          var div, i, id;
          for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            id = divs[i];
            div = document.getElementById(id);
            if(visibleId === id) {
              div.style.display = "block";
            } else {
              div.style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Why dont  you use any library like jQuery which gives you lot more methods to do this job.

`  $('.article-btn').click(function(){
})`

Comment: Hi my knowledge of js is very limite, so I am just piecing together code that I found. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `<script>


        function show(id) {
   Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('div')).forEach(function(item) {
     item.style.display = 'show'
  });
          hide(id);
        }
        function hide() {
          ;
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
</script>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something fishy with your show-hide logic.

Check out my suggestion below, where you can pass an array of IDs, which you want to show. All other elements will be hidden.

```js
function onClick(elements) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.articles div').forEach(articleDiv => articleDiv.style.display = 'none');

  elements.forEach(element => {
    const domEl = document.querySelector('#' + element)
    domEl.style.display = 'block';
  })
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    <a href="#!" class="article-btn" onclick="onClick(['fitness'])">Fitness & Wellness</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#!" class="article-btn" onclick="onClick(['art', 'business'])">Business</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#!" class="article-btn" onclick="onClick(['art'])">Arts & Entertainment</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="articles">
  <div id="fitness">fitness</div>
  <div id="business">business</div>
  <div id="art">art</div>
</div>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: No, at first I only fixed the onclick usage, but now I fixed the whole solution instead.

Comment: Thank you this worked 100% Appreciate your help

Comment: @gru No, the first version didn't fix anything. Giving an onclick attribute an arrow function without invoking it, doesn't do anything at all. The version you have now works excellent.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for your hint, at first it was invalid syntax indeed.  was probably thinking of a framework-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to be running, but every time you receive an ID in your function, you hide everything else with the "hide" function, so in the end, the last ID sent, is the only one that will show, try this:

Call the function once, but pass the IDs as one string separated by commas

```
<a href="#!"  class="article-btn"  onclick="show('el-57d5b6f71db32029,el-e881a23a64890108')">Business</a>
```

Then change your "show" function like this:

```
    function show(ids) {
      let idArr = ids.split(",");
      divs.forEach( x => {
                   div = document.getElementById(x);
                   div.style.display = (idArr.includes(x) ? "block" : "none");
      });
    }
```

What this does, is that it will create an array of IDs based on the parameter you send, and for each item it will check if the ID was sent and show/hide it.

Please let me know if this helps or if you need more details.

EDIT: Formatting in the JavaScript code and simplifying it. Please also note that here I am not validating if the an element with the ID exists, it is only to show you how it can work. It will need additional validations

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
<ul>    
<li>
        <a href="#!"  class="article-btn" data-id="el-57d5b6f71db32029">Fitness & Wellness</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#!"  class="article-btn"  data-id="el-57d5b6f71db32029;el-e881a23a64890108">Business</a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#!"  class="article-btn" data-id="el-65ebd7b2380005a1">Arts & Entertainment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

<div class="articles">
  <div id="el-57d5b6f71db32029" style="display:none;">fitness</div>
   <div id="el-e881a23a64890108" style="display:none;">business</div>
  <div id="el-65ebd7b2380005a1" style="display:none;">art</div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.article-btn').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    show((item.getAttribute('data-id')).split(";"));
  })
})

const show = (id) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.articles>div').forEach(item => {
      if(id.includes(item.getAttribute('id'))){
           item.style["display"] = "block";
      }else{
           item.style["display"] = "none";                    
      } 
    });
}     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline JavaScript is generally discouraged these days, so here's a solution that removes that dependency. It puts the ids of the list items into the dataset instead. You can then create an array from that dataset, iterate over the articles, and if the id is included in the array of ids either hide or show it.

```js
// Cache the list and the articles
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const articles = document.querySelectorAll('.articles div');

// Add an event listener to the list
ul.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Get the node name and the dataset
  // from the element that was clicked
  const { nodeName, dataset } = e.target;

  // Check that it was an anchor
  if (nodeName === 'A') {
    
    // Get an array of ids from the dataset
    const ids = dataset
      .ids.split(',')
      .map(id => id.trim());
    
    // Hide all the articles
    articles.forEach(article => {
      article.classList.add('hide');
    });
    
    // Show the articles where the id is in
    // the list of ids
    articles.forEach(div => {
      if (ids.includes(div.id)) {
        div.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
  
  }

}
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
ul li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-ids="el-57d5b6f71db32029">Fitness & Wellness</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-ids="el-57d5b6f71db32029, el-e881a23a64890108">Business</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-ids= "el-65ebd7b2380005a1">Arts & Entertainment</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="articles">
  <div id="el-57d5b6f71db32029" class="hide">fitness</div>
  <div id="el-e881a23a64890108" class="hide">business</div>
  <div id="el-65ebd7b2380005a1" class="hide">art</div>
</div>
```